# C++ calling an inherited constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a header file, "Item.h", which "Sword.h" inherits, like this:

```
#ifndef SWORD_H
#define SWORD_H

#include "Item.h"

class Sword: public Item {
public:
    Sword(int damage);
    ~Sword();
};
#endif
```

My Item.h is this:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

class Item{
public:
   int damage;

   Item(int damage);
   int GetDamage();
};
#endif
```

And then I have a file, "Sword.cpp", that I want to call the Item constructor from (this is the Item.cpp):

```
#include "Item.h"

Item::Item(int damage)
{
   this->damage = damage;
}

int Item::GetDamage()
{
   return damage;
}
```

I basically want Sword.cpp to be a child class of Item.cpp, so that I can use Item's functions, and set variables such as `Damage` from Sword.cpp. I've been told there is no way to inherit constructors in C++ though, so how could I do this? Some answers seem to use the explicit keyword, but I can never get it to work.

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually inherit constructors. It is all-or nothing though, you can't select which ones. This is how you do it:

```
class Sword: public Item {
public:
    using Item::Item;
    ~Sword();
};
```

If you are stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler, then you need to declare the constructor and implement it yourself. This would be the implementation in `Sword.cpp`:

```
Sword::Sword(int damage) : Item(damage) {}
```

Comment: This is only available in C++11 and was one of the last features to be implemented in gcc (4.8)

Comment: And is not available in visual studio

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense.! @MooingDuck, why is the above mentioned "method" not available in visual studio?

Comment: @MooingDuck I had heard somewhere that VS was now C++11 language complete. Perhaps I got that wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza: They cleverly announced that their C++11 _standard library_ was complete. However, VC++ doesn't have all of the language features, and as such, some of the library bits are still quirky as a side effect.  Additionally, some new library bits are complete, but broken.  (moving variables into a thread constructor doesn't compile).  [C++11 status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

Comment: @MooingDuck, are you sure about that? I just compiled code which does exactly that in VS2012 Update 4.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's interesting, good to know. GCC and CLANG were language complete first (bar a few bugs). I don't think either is library complete yet.

Comment: @DanShield: Surprisingly, when I tested with VS2013, `using Item::Item;` compiled!  However, I got two warnings: `warning C4510: 'Sword' : default constructor could not be generated`, and `warning C4610: struct 'Sword' can never be instantiated - user defined constructor required`.  Attempting to _use_ the `int` constructor gave me `error C2664: 'Sword::Sword(const Sword &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Sword &'`.  Did your test with VS2012U4 not produce these?

Comment: @MooingDuck My mistake. When I used the default (0 parameter) constructor, everything compiled/ran fine. When using the `int` constructor VS2012 Update 4 generates the same errors you received in VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

You don't inherit the constructor because the constructor has the same name as the class (and obviously parent and child must have different names). But you can use the parent's constructor in the child's constructor

```
    Sword()
    : Item(3)    // Call the superclass constructor and set damage to 3
    {
        // do something 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the Sword constructor the following way

```
Sword(int damage) : Item( damage ) {}
```

Also it would be better if the destructor of Item were virtual and data member damage should have access control protected. For example

```
class Item{
protected:
   int damage;
public:
   Item(int damage);
   virtual ~Item() = default;
   int GetDamage();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the parent's constructor from your derived class's constructor like this:

`Sword(int damage):
Item(damage)
{
}`